How to handle webhook and aiogram3 bot at the same time?
I need somehow to get data from my webhook (using Flask not connected with bot) and using it in the aiogram bot.
I dont see any methods or ideas how to do this.
Already tried with async and threading, both dont work with me.

Basically, i just created an API for getting all the data by get-request that im sending using the bot. Works perfect.
